# SQL like statement, issue with singular, plural keyword

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
 for (String column : searchCols) {
            for (String keyword : keywords) { 
                listAllSql.append(getDBColumnName(column));
                listAllSql.append(" like "); //like
                listAllSql.append("'%");     //'%vision%'
                listAllSql.append(keyword); 
                listAllSql.append("%'"); 
                listAllSql.append(" or ");
            }
```

Here is a snippet of of the code. I pass a keyword for example "Networks" to be searched for. I want the statement to return me result event if it finds "Network" (Singular) as well as those which contains "Networks" (plural). What changes to do I make to the above statement to achieve this. I am actually working with 'SQLite' Manager as an add on on Mozilla Firefox FYI.

Comment: Do you want to find `network` if the keyword is `networks` also?

Comment: basically lets say I pass 'Networks', it finds result with 'Network'

Answer (score 0):

You could just add to the top (not sure on the language):

```
for (String keyword : keywords) { 
    if right(keyword,1) = "s" and length(keyword) > 1 then
        keyword = left(keyword,length(keyword)-1)
    end if
    listAllSql.append.....
```

you may run into problems where they search for 'as' and returns all which contain 'a' but finding words that are plural and not just ending with s will be MUCH harder, also generally false positives in a search are better than false negatives (in my opinion).